# Pyramid HTTP redirect after AJAX post

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, pyramid, http-redirect

Is it possible to redirect to another page after a jquery post to the server?  Once the user logs in, I want to return a json response or redirect to another page.  I know the correct view callable is being called, because I can see a log statement from the server.

Here's my jquery post:

```
function postToServer(url, params) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                return data;
            },
            201: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                return data;
            },
            400: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It's pretty basic and seems to work well.  Whenever I return json, it handles the response correctly.

Here are my views:

```
#LOGIN
class LoginView(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.ctx = core.context()

    @view_config(route_name="login", request_method='GET')
    def get(self):
        template = "project:templates/login/login.mak"
        context = {}
        return render_to_response(template, context, request=self.request)

    @view_config(route_name="login", request_method='POST')
    def post(self):
        url = self.request.route_url('dashboard')
        print 'url: ' + url        
        #log user in and get credentials

        json = getJsonCredentialsObject()
        return Response('json', json)

#DASHBOARD
class DashboardView(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.ctx = core.context()

    @view_config(route_name="dashboard", request_method='GET')
    def get(self):
        print "in dashboard"
        template = "project:templates/dashboard/dashboard.mak"
        session = self.request.session
        context = {}
        return render_to_response(template, context, request=self.request)
```

I'd like the post method in the Login class to handle the interaction, but when I try to redirect here using "return HTTPFound(location=self.request.route_url('/dashboard'))" nothing happens.  I'm also having trouble getting the request.json_body object out of the request (it's null), but that's another issue. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to achieve what you want you can't return pyramid Redirect to ajax call.

Return json data with the status and redirect url

Then on front end you can redirect user on success

`window.location = http://redirecturlhere`

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Pyramid. It is just not possible to trigger a redirection from an AJAX call. It has to be performed client-side as part of code running after receiving and processing the data returned by the server.

Comment: Is there any way to do this on the server?  I have a javascript solution working that does the same thing you're suggesting, but I was really hoping to avoid any needless calls to the server.

Comment: @JeffCompton Just do a tradtional form post from your html, (dont use ajax)?  Then you cna handle rederict on server

Comment: @CRUSADER, Well that's disappointing.  Thank you for your response. I guess I'm stuck doing it with javascript.

Answer (score 4):

When using AJAX, your browser is not requesting a page to display.

A redirect is merely pointing the client to a different URL to get the response from, and when doing that with AJAX, the browser simply gets the AJAX response from the new location instead. If you were loading a page, the redirect means that the data is simply loaded from another location instead.

In other words, a response to an AJAX request is never going to change the browser page in and off itself. You'll need to do that with JavaScript code instead. Return a URL from your POST handler, then use `window.location = newurl`.